# Google Apps Script - Replace a formula in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, replace, google-apps-script

In the code below, I am trying to read in a 2d array (157 rows, 2 columns), which are all formulas.  I need to then delete a part of the formula from each cell, then write it back to the sheet in the same range (prior to this step, I am deleting the sheet that this portion of the formula is referencing).  When I run the debugger, everything runs fine, but my values do not get replaced.  Any thoughts?

```
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Employee List'));
var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var empid = as.getLastRow();

var hrsRange = as.getRange(1, 3, empid, 2).getFormulas();
var i = 1;
while(i < empid)
{

  var emp = as.getRange(i, 2).getA1Notation();
  if (cpr == 20)
  {
    while(i < hrsRange.length)
    {
      var regHrs = "+sumif('" + array[x] + "'!O:O,$" + emp + ",'" + array[x] + "'!P:P)";
      var otHrs = "+sumif('" + array[x] + "'!O:O,$" + emp + ",'" + array[x] + "'!Q:Q)";
      hrsRange[i-1][0].toString().replace(regHrs,"");
      hrsRange[i-1][1].toString().replace(otHrs,"");

      i++;
    }
  } else {
    while(i < hrsRange.length)
    {
      var regHrs = "+sumif('" + array[x] + "'!O:O,$" + emp + ",'" + array[x] + "'!Q:Q)";
      var otHrs = "+sumif('" + array[x] + "'!O:O,$" + emp + ",'" + array[x] + "'!R:R)";
      hrsRange[i-1][0].toString().replace(regHrs,"");
      hrsRange[i-1][1].toString().replace(otHrs,"");

      i++;
    }
  }

  i++;
}

as.getRange(1, 3, empid, 2).setFormulas(hrsRange);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
      hrsRange[i-1][0].toString().replace(regHrs,"");
```

will return a string, not actually modify `hrsRange[i-1][0]` .

You'll need to assign the resulting string to `hrsRange[i-1][0]`:

```
 hrsRange[i-1][0]=hrsRange[i-1][0].toString().replace(regHrs,"");
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I knew I was missing something simple.